# This sql script returns different results on different MySQL server versions?

Tags: mysql

I have tried it on 5.5.35 and 5.6.19. Both returning different results. 
I am basically trying to find an exact date a company reached above a certain total point value (250 in this case)

If I don't have an error on my final sql query, 5.5.35 seems to return expected results.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company_sales;

CREATE TABLE `company_sales` (
  `id_company_sales` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `points` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cancelled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cnd1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cnd2` varchar(128) DEFAULT '',
  `cnd3` mediumint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_company_sales`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cnd1_UNIQUE` (`cnd1`),
  KEY `index3` (`company_id`,`date`),
  KEY `order_id` (`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=56919 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (48712,6978,64390,'0000-00-00',76.96,1,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (49093,6978,0,'2014-11-01',256.03,0,NULL,'starting',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (47286,6978,63122,'2014-11-23',84.44,1,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (48956,6978,64811,'2014-11-28',76.96,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (48962,6978,64817,'2014-11-28',84.44,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (49042,6978,64900,'2014-11-28',57.52,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (49048,6978,64905,'2014-11-28',28.76,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (49090,6978,64945,'2014-11-28',8.35,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (53416,6978,0,'2014-12-01',106.80,0,NULL,'starting',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (53415,6978,69189,'2014-12-09',26.10,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (53459,6978,69231,'2014-12-09',16.55,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (53959,6978,69701,'2014-12-10',64.15,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (57880,4605,73805,'2014-12-18',92.13,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (57879,6212,73804,'2014-12-18',21.12,0,NULL,'',0);
INSERT INTO `company_sales` (`id_company_sales`,`company_id`,`order_id`,`date`,`points`,`cancelled`,`cnd1`,`cnd2`,`cnd3`) VALUES (57878,7395,73626,'0000-00-00',39.97,1,NULL,'',0);


SELECT 
    NULL AS id_company_sales,
    NULL AS date,
    NULL AS points,
    NULL AS total
FROM DUAL WHERE
    (@total:=0) 
UNION SELECT 
    id_company_sales,
    (date),
    points,
    @total:=@total + points AS total
FROM
    company_sales cs
WHERE
        cs.company_id = 6978
        AND cs.date >= '2014-11-21'
        AND cs.date <= '2014-12-21'
        AND cs.cancelled = 0
        AND cs.order_id != 0
        AND @total < 250
ORDER BY id_company_sales DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Edit: I have filed a bug report on MySQL
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75266

Comment: Your SQL query please.

Comment: @davidstrachan It's the last one, select query

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle of OP's schema and query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5ec83/1

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems like the value of `@total` in the WHERE clause is being calculated at different times (e.g. pre-fix and post-fix) in 5.5.x versus 5.6.x

Answer (score 0):

Using user-defined variables (e.g. `@total`) like this is somewhat non-deterministic. It will likely work provided you are running the same query on the same MySQL version. However, on a MySQL version update, the query optimizer may have changed and execute the same query differently internally.

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) also states that:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> SET @a = @a + 1;
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined.

In summary: the result of the same query may or may not change from MySQL version to MySQL version. There is no guarantee that the query will work as expected in any given MySQL version.